# Disable Drush backend messages by default

Tags: drush

I am having a problem with drush backend message, how do I disable "--backend" by default ?

```
command:
$ drush make drupal-org.make drupal

result:
$ drush make drupal-org.make drupal
DRUSH_BACKEND:{"type":"notice","message":"Command dispatch complete","timestamp"
:1364518974.3749,"memory":6182608,"error":null,"packet":"log"}

 DRUSH_BACKEND:{"type":"memory","message":"Peak memory usage was 6.36 MB","times
tamp":1364518974.375,"memory":6183144,"error":null,"packet":"log"}drupal-7.21 do
wnloaded.    [ok]
```

everything is working properly but I do not want to see the "backend json" output on the console.

```
$ drush --version
drush version 5.0-dev

$ git --version
git version 1.8.0.msysgit.0

$ uname -a
MINGW32_NT-6.1 PC 1.0.12(0.46/3/2) 2011-07-20 17:52 i686 Win7
```

Comment: It shouldn't be doing that.  Pull the latest 7.x-5.x, and also try with the latest 8.x-6.x.  Then, if you're still having problems, report your findings in the Drush issue queue.

Comment: I am having the same issue under Ubuntu, any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall cleanly that version of `drush` as 5.0 is very old now. Uninstall using pear if you installed that way, using Composer, or manually checking `which drush` and remove symlinks, drush folder, backup and then remove `~/.drush`.

Look at the [Drush install page](http://docs.drush.org/en/7.x/install/) to see what drush version you need for Drupal version you are working with. Then install drush using Composer which is the recommended way.

This message should be gone then. Good luck!